# Laravel - npm run dev error

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть такая проблема:

я как всегда пишу в терминал composer create-project laravel/laravel project:
и у меня создаеться проект laravel 'project', после этого я в директории проекта пишу:

composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue --auth

npm install

npm run dev

и после выполнения последней команды вот такое:

alex@pc:~/LaravelPrj$ npm run dev

> @ dev /home/alex/LaravelPrj
> npm run development

> @ development /home/alex/LaravelPrj
> mix

[webpack-cli] /home/alex/LaravelPrj/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:18
static _primary = null;
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/home/alex/LaravelPrj/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
at Module._compile (/home/alex/LaravelPrj/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:184:36)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (/home/alex/LaravelPrj/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
at module.exports (/home/alex/LaravelPrj/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:2:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/alex/.npm/_logs/2021-01-25T11_30_29_373Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/alex/.npm/_logs/2021-01-25T11_30_29_388Z-debug.log

это также не помогает:

rm -rf node_modules

rm package-lock.json yarn.lock

npm cache clear --force

npm install

ну и логи:

alex@pc:~/laravel/blog$ cat /home/alex/.npm/_logs/2021-01-25T12_06_50_464Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]

2 info using npm@6.14.4

3 info using node@v10.19.0

4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]

5 info lifecycle @~predev: @

6 info lifecycle @~dev: @

7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle
/node-gyp-bin:/home/alex/laravel/blog/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: /home/alex/laravel/blog

10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development' ]

11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null

12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script

13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`

13 verbose stack Exit status 1

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (/usr/share
/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/share
/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)

13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)

13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
(internal/child_process.js:259:5)

14 verbose pkgid @

15 verbose cwd /home/alex/laravel/blog

16 verbose Linux 5.4.0-64-generic

17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"

18 verbose node v10.19.0

19 verbose npm  v6.14.4

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 1

22 error @ dev: `npm run development`

22 error Exit status 1

23 error Failed at the @ dev script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
additional logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче говоря у меня эта фигня была из за того что у меня была старая версия nodejs, вот так я все исправил:

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt install nodejs
node -v
```

и теперь у меня новая версия ноды:
v15.6.0

Comment: И если что у меня ос: Linux mint